# How to start custom commands when django server starts in PyCharm?

Tags: python, pycharm

Usually, after Django local server start (via PyCharm **Run**), I'm open few tabs and started *Celery*, *Flower* and *RabbitMQ* in separated tabs.

Can I start *Celery*, *Flower* and *RabbitMQ* from **Run/Debug Configuration** in PyCharm?

Comment: in Run/Debug Configurations -> Configuration and at the bottom of the window you can find `Before launch`. You can define tasks/scripts/commands to start before launching of your Command. But there aren't any configuration for after-tasks

Comment: You can may be define in the task of rabbitmq to start celery and flower before. in flower to start django before. If you start rabbitmq, it will start all of your commands. It can may be work. you must test it ;)

Comment: @julivico I have added 3 external tools, but because all of this programs run in foreground, only first started and suspended start of other. How I can fix this?

Comment: so, now i understand it. You can try to define 3 Configurations (python) for celery, flower, rabbitmq in `Run/Debug Comnfiguration`. For each Configuration you set only one `Before Launch` to your matching external tool. So that each configuration will only start one tool. Than you can define a new configuration (Compound). The Compound Configuration can start 4 tasks separate and you will see 4 running tabs. But for what you want, i will write a bash script. it's easier